# Button is changing while hovering with different font weight and border none

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make some decoration on button, my goal just to make a button without border, and the button's font become bolder.

I use simple css like this

```
.button {
...
font-weight: 500;
border: none;
}

.button:hover{
font-weight:600;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but I got this result:
[image]

any explanation and solution??

Answer (score 2):

You can set width to avoid this.

```css
.button {
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #ea0c54;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: .3s;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .button:hover {
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<button class="button">Hover Me</button>
```

Comment: thank a bunch for the solution. If I wanna learn about why that could happen? any keyword suggestion on google? I'm bad in English by the way.